# Leaflet marker numbers appearing to high on marker

Tags: css, leaflet

In this leaflet@1.9.2 map https://net-control.us/mapcopy.php the marker number is on top of the marker instead of inside the hole for it. A typical marker definition looks like this;

```
var _WA0TJT = new L.marker(new L.latLng(39.2028965,-94.602876),{ 
                rotationAngle: 0,
                rotationOrigin: 'bottom',
                contextmenu: true,
                contextmenuWidth: 140,
                contextmenuItems: [{ text: 'Click here to add mileage circles', callback: circleKoords}],  
                             
icon: new L.NumberedGreenDivIcon({number: '5' }),
                title:`marker_5` }).addTo(fg).bindPopup(`
<div class='cc' style='text-transform:uppercase;'>5<br><b>WA0TJT</b><br> ID: #000013<br>Keith Kaiser<br>Platte  Co., MO Dist: A<br>39.2028965, -94.602876<br>EM29QE<br><a href='https://what3words.com/guiding.confusion.towards?maptype=osm' target='_blank'>///guiding.confusion.towards</a></div><br><br>
<div class='cc'> <a href='http://www.findu.com/cgi-bin/map-near.cgi?lat=39.2028965&lon=-94.602876&cnt=10' target='_blank'>Nearby APRS stations</a></div><br><br>
                `).openPopup();
                
$(`_WA0TJT`._icon).addClass(`greenmrkr`);
                stationMarkers.push(_WA0TJT);
```

When first written the problem wasn't happening, it started some months back. I've looked at every CSS and marker definition to fix it. If you have the bandwidth please take a look and give me a suggestion how to fix.

Comment: Is there any code for `NumberedGreenDivIcon`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened there but, element `<div class="number">12</div>` has styles

```css
.leaflet-marker-icon .number {
    position: relative;
    top: -44px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

change to

```css
.leaflet-marker-icon .number {
    position: fixed;
    top: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue. I can't answer what happened either but I will say when this got changed is a mystery.